# SCP from remote CentOS to Ubunto host

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, scp, sshd

I am having real trouble establishing both SSH and SCP. I need to get some files off my guest machine onto host.

I can ping my host vboxnet0 IP set up in VirtualBox. And vice versa. I have not yet been able to log in. Permission denied.

Not been able to SSH from host, or SCP from VM despite pings and many iterations on ssh and scp etc.

Could someone spell out the sshd_config parameters that will allow me to complete this transfer?

Any help very much welcome.

[image]

Comment: `phil@Phil-Ubuntu@172.17.0.1` looks wrong. The syntax is `user@host`, probably `phil@172.17.0.1` or `phil@Phil-Ubuntu` is all you need.

Comment: tried both of these unfortunately no luck

Comment: Although it could be correct `prushton.cast` is a strange name for a private key and your home dir is a strange place to place it in. Most likely your key is in the regular place. It seems to me that you are making `scp` more complicated then it should be. What is the result of `scp only-one-file your-user-at-the-other-system@ip-of-the-other-system:` (do not forget the column at the end)